# Problema al Visualizar datos de mi web en un hosting

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, cpanel

Tengo un problema y no se a que se debe, pero acabo de subir una página web a un hosting que recien adquirí. El problema es que no me muestran las consultas `"SELECT"` en la página web, pero si puedo hacer un `"INSERT"`. Pero en el phpMyadmin todas las funciones ejecutan sin ningún error, el usuario que hace la conexión tiene todos los privilegios con la BD. Y si yo hago un registro haciendo un `SELECT`(busco el dato para ver si está registrado o no el dato) no registra. Y a mi suponer el `SELECT` no imprime el dato buscado al momento de mostrar en la página web, no se tal vez falte alguna configuracion en mi Cpanel o código mal.

---privilegios del usuario quien hace conexión con la BD
[image: Privilegios del usuario quien hace conexión con la BD]

Tal vez mi código tenga un error o el proveedor de hosting pero el código es éste, Espero si alguien me pueda ayudar.

---código del select
[image: Codigo de mi select]

Comment: Sugiero que pongas el texto del código en vez de la imagen. Casi seguro que el problema es el código. Por ejemplo `get_result()` no funciona si no tienes el driver `mysqlnd` instalado. Prueba una consulta con `query`, no con  `prerare` y sin usar `get_result()` a ver si es eso. Supongo que habrás verificado que la conexión funciona bien.

Answer (score 0):

Yo la consulta la haria con el query en vez del prepare, por experiencia propia me ha dado menos problema.

Tú codigo quedaría así:

```
    require('files/date/based.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM anio";
if($result = mysqli_query($Conexion, $sql)){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<span>".$row['anio']."</span>";
    }
}
```